# First nodejs application deployment issue

Tags: node.js, express

I am new nodejs, created a project from github. I am getting error after deploying the application. Please help to debug or resolve the issue. I want to navigate to the client page

https://github.com/susannit/demobtgateway

After server restarted successfully 
http://localhost:3000/ gives Cannot GET /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try it. In file **app.js**, they just using `app.post()`.
Here

```
app.post('/api/v1/token', function (request, response) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.json({
      "client_token": res.clientToken
    });
  });
});
```

So you can run that code with method "http post".
uhm... just one things...
You want run demo with Get then add this code in your code:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.json({
      "client_token": 'Hello, I'm Tungns'
    });
  });
});
```

So i hope help you!

Comment: Thanks Tung. It helped me.

Comment: @Sudharsan: We can talk on skype, right? Do you have skype? or you can add for: tungtrum17 on skype.Thanks